# How do I verify if every list contains a common number?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numbers, set

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0,1,0]
c = [5,1,5]

if set(a)&set(b)&set(c) is True:
    print("aa")
else:
    print('ss')
```

Every list contains the number 1 so I want it to print `aa` but it prints `ss` even if I change `True` to `False`.

Comment: Why do you need `n`?

Comment: @wil93: *I removed it.*

Comment: @KevinGuan uhm... ok, well, maybe OP put it here for a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `is True`

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[0,1,0]
c=[5,1,5]
if set(a)&set(b)&set(c):
    print("aa")
else:
    print('ss')
```

`set(a)&set(b)&set(c)` returns `set([1])` which is not `True`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `set(a)&set(b)&set(c)` is truthy, but not the same object as `True`, which is what you are checking with `set(a)&set(b)&set(c) is True` (they have different ids):

```
>>> id(set(a)&set(b)&set(c)) 
140627137313352
>>> id(True)
9544944
```

Just leave the `is True` part out, i.e.

```
if set(a)&set(b)&set(c): # truthy if not empty
    print('aa')
else:
    print('ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

you're if statement is a bit wrong. if you want to see if 1 is in a,b,c try

```
if 1 in a and b and c:

    print('aa')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [set.intersection()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0,1,0]
c = [5,1,5]

d = set.intersection(set(a), set(b), set(c)) #set([1])
```